# Google Chrome weird cursor blink on pages, never seen 'em before

Tags: google-chrome, security, contenteditable

recently noticed that Google chrome elements upon click showing cursor blink and that's spooky. HTML page elements became editable?   It's not happening with Mozilla, and the extensions enabled on chrome are,

- Apollo Client Developer Tools,
- Authenticator
- Vue.JS Tools

On Firefox, it's allowing to select and no cursor blinks and that's the default behaviour.

Demo of problem:

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 243):

An easy solution is to press the <kbd>F7</kbd> key on the Chrome browser.

This method makes it easy to enable/disable cursor blinking problem.

Comment: You saved my eyes :)) I thought it is the new Chrome feature

Comment: @HenryBui Actually it is the chrome feature . Caret Browsing . https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10129654?hl=en

Answer (score 78):

There's an option called **Navigate pages with a text cursor** in Accessibility settings, you'll need to disable this option.

Go to `Chrome Settings ​​→ Advanced → Accessibility`, find the `Navigate pages with a text cursor` option, and disable it.

Ref. https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/77878717?hl=en

Answer (score 7):

Disabled this and now its not showing the cursor blinking

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That means **caret browsing** has been enabled in your browser (i.e. Chrome)

- You can press **`F7`** key to disable the caret browsing
  straightaway, which is default keyboard shortcut in browsers.
- Otherwise you can also disable caret browsing through Browser
  Settings. As of today, the settings are named as:

> Navigate pages with a text cursor (Chrome)
>
> Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages (Firefox)

---

***What is caret browsing?***

That allows the user to move around, highlight selections with the keyboard rather than a mouse. Users most familiar with keyboard can opt for caret browsing easier to use for selecting text.
The *caret* is nothing but the name of the vertical `|` text cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a touchscreen and the other solutions don't work, I just tapped the touch screen a few times, and that worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

I have the same problem here in all websites.

The problem is not extensions but the Chrome browser on version 86.

I downloaded Chrome 87 beta and problem is fixed.

So wait until release version 87.

Answer (score -3):

there is a way to round this issue ==>

by adding this to your global.css you can avoid this blinking cursor

```
*:not(input) {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
}
```