# Is there a way to fix this bug in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, debugging

I'm learning HTML and CSS (I'm a beginner) but I have a problem.
This is my html code (quit simple):

```html
<div style="height: 22px; width: 40px; background-color: lightgray;"></div>
```

When the page is displayed in Microsoft Edge, no problem.
But in Chrome 89, the browser show a cursor when you click on the `div`. But we can't enter text. Why Chrome is doing this ?

Is your browser showing this cursor too ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does [Google Chrome weird cursor blink on pages, never seen 'em before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64499328/google-chrome-weird-cursor-blink-on-pages-never-seen-em-before) help?

Comment: It works! You saved my day! Thanks a lot! :)