# how to stop cursor from blinking on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cursor, blink

My MacBook's version is Sonoma 14.0. I hope to disable cursor blinking on Chrome.app. This question has been asked before [Google Chrome weird cursor blink on pages, never seen 'em before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64499328/google-chrome-weird-cursor-blink-on-pages-never-seen-em-before). I tried to toggle on "Navigate pages with a text cursor" but it takes no effect.